# Fusion 360: Measurement issues to Slicer Software

Tags: mechanical-engineering, cad, autocad

So I made a design for the Autodesk Competition but for some reason, I have never had this issue, but when I export to .obj and open in S3D, it doesn't convert the measurements. My meaning: I have a 3.5x3.5x10 inch design but in S3D it reads as 3.5x3.5x10mm and I do not know how to fix this. Any help would be great!

Comment: I suppose your dimension settings in Fusion360 are not the same as in S3D. In Fusion you can rescale your drawings (modify - scale) which should solve your problem. 1 inch = 25.4mm

Comment: How do I rescale to mm?

Comment: From the Fusion360 documentation: 
    In the Model workspace, select Modify > Scale.
    Select the body or bodies to scale, and pick a fixed anchor point for the scaling.
    Choose a Scale Type from the dialog:
        Uniform. Scale the body uniformly on all axes.
        Non Uniform. Scale along the x, y, and z axes separately.
    Use the manipulators or the dialog to set the scale distance (-0.5 to halve the size or 2 to double the size, for example).
    Right-click and click OK to finish the command.

In your case the scaletype will be "uniform" and the scale factor "25.4"